# Up-to-date examples for using the Google Drive APs That Really Work

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

The company I work for has many gigabytes of data on the Google Drive cloud.  A lot of this data is contained in individual files of several Gigabytes.

We would like to operate on this data:

- a file at a time
- remotely (without downloading a whole file to local disk
- with COTS applications that see the cloud as a local hard disk and may access the file non-linearly i.e. doing seeks and partial fetches from within a file
- on Windows

I am trying to write a virtual disk driver that would appear to a COTS application as just another disk drive with read-only permissions.  I am working in C# .net Visual Studio.  There is nothing to require this development environment it's just one that I am comfortable using and should have the capabilities to do the job.  I could be convinced to switch environments if this is a blocking impediment.

My biggest problem is that Google is changing their APIs faster than they are documenting the changes.  I have found examples for downloading a (partial) file using HTTP and for reading directories to get file IDs but when I try to run them they just don't work.  If they would work I'd have the building blocks for putting together a disk interface.

For example:
Installing the Google Drive API and Client Library was a challenge.  The direction page https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs and its subsequent links to the library were clearly written before the latest V2 authentication library was released this month (October 2013).  The C# code in the quick-start example produces all types of warnings about deprecated and obsolete functions that are going to go away with the next release but no guidance (yet) on the new equivalents.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list shows how to list files on a drive.  When I execute the Try It! at the bottom of the page without parameters I get a list of all my files.  When I try to limit it with a search query string parameter q on the page) I get a 500 Internal Server error.  This is before I try to use the program that should do this.

Once I have a file ID (or I take several from the above page execution without queries, the page developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get has a Try It! for retrieving a file.  I am always getting a 401 error (invalid ID).

I am very tempted to put this project aside for a few weeks and see what Google comes up with in new documentation.  Of course that won't please my boss.  Alternatively, is there anyone else trying to work with the Google Drive API in a similar manner that is willing to share/collaborate?

Comment: I would put it aside permanently. Google Drive was not architected to provide a cloud equivalent of a physical device. Just for starters, the whole API is largely store and forward between the API layer and the Drive layer. The low level seek access doesn't exist and probably never will. Regarding the specific issues you have encountered, my strong advice is to separate the issues of authentication/authorisation from the drive access itself. You'll find it much simpler to solve them as separate problems.

Comment: Please send the request headers, otherwise it's impossible to point out what the problem is.